# Restricting the type on function argument in Node.js and TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

Working on a Node.js project and using TypeScript.

I'm trying to restrict a functions argument type to a specific base class. I'm new with both Node & TypeScript and come from a C# background, so likely not quite understanding some of the characteristics of the lang.

Take these snippets.

First, my class declarations

```
class DTO{
}

class userDTO extends DTO{
    @IsDefined({message:"Username required"})
    @Expose()
    @Length(1,10, {message:"min 1 max 10"})
    username:String;    
  }
  
class badDTO {
    name:String;
}
```

Now I will create instances:

```
let user = new userDTO();
user.username = "My username";

let isUserDTO = user instanceof DTO; // Evaluates true

let bad = new badDTO();
bad.name = "Bob";

let isBadDTO = user instanceof DTO; // Evaluates false
```

Here is the signature of the method I intend to call

```
export default function ValidateDTO(objToValidate:DTO, validateMissingProperties:boolean): Array<string>{
    return [];
}
```

Finally, when I actually call the function.

```
let userErrors = ValidateDTO(user, true);

// Why is this allowed?
let badErr = ValidateDTO(bad, true);
```

I am expecting the 2nd ValidateDTO to show me a warning and not actually run because 'bad' is not a DTO as proven by instanceOf above - if i try passing a string as the 2nd arg I see an error, which is what i expected from passing a non-DTO as the first arg.

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong? How can I restrict the type of object passed into a function.

Happy to share other code as required too. Not sure what else i might be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not at all alone being surprised by this. :-) One of the key things about the TypeScript type system is that it's [*structural*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) (based on structure), not [*nominal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) (based on names). As long as something has the minimum structure necessary, it matches even if it has a different ancestry. That means **any** object will be accepted by the type system as your `DTO` type because your `DTO` type has no properties, so all objects match it.

That's mostly a *feature*, but sometimes you want to disable it. The usual approach when you want to disable it is to use a branding property:

```typescript
class DTO {
    __brand = "DTO" as const;
}
```

Now, only objects that have a `__brand` property with the value `"DTO"` will be allowed where `DTO` objects are expected by the type system.

---

Here's a complete example with some minor changes to be more in keeping with JavaScript/TypeScript naming conventions and to supply some bits that were missing in the question code (presumably to keep it short! :-) ):

```typescript
class DTO {
    __brand = "DTO" as const;
}

class UserDTO extends DTO {
    /* Commenting these out as they're not relevant to the question.
    @IsDefined({message:"Username required"})
    @Expose()
    @Length(1,10, {message:"min 1 max 10"})
    */
    username: string;
    
    constructor(username: string) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
    }
}
  
class BadDTO {
    name: string = "";
}

function validateDTO(objToValidate: DTO, validateMissingProperties: boolean): string[] {
    return [];
}

// Okay
validateDTO(new UserDTO("Joe"), true);

// Disallowed by the type system
validateDTO(new BadDTO(), false);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiAqB5aBvAUNT0D62BGATmAHYAm0AvNAEQKLXSTTAD2xEALgNxoC+aaUJBgBVCAFMCdaOIAeHcWRjT0WaAHoAVNADCLALb7FHAJbEA5tA4ALcROgsArh0Ywb4gJ4ByAuOjEWF18QcQA3EhcOFitbaABHRztTNgA6DCwAAQBJCFhxADMzcVIAChQjKDBzcQAuajFJYjAjaF8Ek19Sal4ASnTMDIBRWQAHFgkSvrUMgBlFcxsSgEYAGiWABhXUCogq2up9M2gl6H0wWWP17qmsTXV+6EcJAiajGuhOAjNzHjUH1nYHAIjmAUQIJSejWatQ+QO+PVQDzUEEcI0kk1+aiwNhMEBSkJe0Moj2er3EmMw-H4mEE4Cg0AAQmBSCoHmT3p9vsTqNQePw0PlHMRQSY2NBwiATKQwAo6CUWHgAFbwFgANTAkulCnedC2EqlMvEAFlcRBvgAFAgsNEEUx2d54FgsEIkHocuEWADaAF1EWpfBxHC9oD6+QJ1OpoIgANZgDxofVa8Ry4jiADu0AaUiQJWoACkWOJqD0tkDEj0eGgI3BcRqQCw08VoHgPDE-BwPGiPh5OOJ9AmNQbZTnUxmmSycyXoPkNRIK2ggA)

---

Side note 2: In that example I added a constructor to `UserDTO` that initialized the `username` property. TypeScript has a shorthand for when you want to use a constructor paramter to initialize an instance property, this is functionally identical to the `UserDTO` in my example:

```typescript
class UserDTO extends DTO {
    /* Commenting these out as they're not relevant to the question.
    @IsDefined({message:"Username required"})
    @Expose()
    @Length(1,10, {message:"min 1 max 10"})
    */
    //−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− note no `username` declaration here
    
    constructor(public username: string) {
    //          ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− note adding `public`
        super();
        // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− note no code here to do the
        // initialization; it's implicit in the `public` declaration above
    }
}
```

Which you use is a matter of style.

Comment: I love your explanation - thank you! When I try using your code example I get warnings in VS Code that "cannot find name 'as'" on the 'as' word and "';' expected" when on the const word. Tried copy/pasting too.

Comment: if i drop the 'as const' it works just as you described. Thanks so much - so is this the norm best practice?

Comment: @DarrenWainwright - I've updated the answer with a full example. You'll want the `as const` so that it's a compilation-time constant value, not just a string property whose value could be changed at runtime. :-) Yes, for the situations where you care about this, it's normal practice to use branding, but it's also normal practice to avoid caring where possible. :-D

Comment: T.K Crowder - thank you again. I can't get it to compile if i leave the 'as const' in place. just get the squiggles. I'm using Node 14.14 and TypeScript 4.0.5

Comment: Never mind - I'm clearly blind..... it works just as you describe; I had : in place of =. Thank you again!

Comment: @DarrenWainwright - That wasn't you -- I accidentally put `:` instead of `=` and fixed it later, so you must have seen it before I fixed it. :-)

Comment: ah, ok cool. THank you for the additional info, and side notes too. Super helpful